# Determine if a point lies on a plane given an equation in standard form

Tags: linear-algebra

I have stumbled across a simple 3 mark question in an old exam paper.

The question states:

> Does the point $(8, 4, -5)$ lie on the plane $7x - 3y + 4z = 8$

Now I am thinking it's simply a matter of taking the point provided and substituting this point in where I see x, y and z respectively and if the solution is not equal to 8 then the point does not in fact lie on the plane.

I'm just refreshing on basics so just making sure I am applying myself correctly here.

Thanks

Comment: You're perfectly correct.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for quick response :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. If a point satisfies the equation of a plane then that point lies on that plane.